# How to close the moodstock scanner in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, image-recognition

following the moodstock guide I can't go on. My problem is about the closing of the scannerviewcontroller. I want to close it when the scanner return a result.
thanks in advance

sorry for my english 
ps : i am italian

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/vision#scanning), it looks like would need to implement the `MSAutoScannerSessionDelegate` methods.

If you wish to do something when the scanner returns a result, use the delegate method:

```
- (void)session:(id)scannerSession didFindResult:(MSResult *)result
{
  // Delegate callback
  // Write your code here
}
```